# How do I copy files from a remote computer (running Linux) to my Windows computer using scp?

Tags: linux, windows, putty

I usually work in Linux and when I want a file from my remote computer, I just give the `scp` command from my local side. Now that I work in Windows, I don't know how I can do the same. I can access my remote computer through PuTTY, but I don't know what command I can write in my remote computer terminal to let it copy to my local computer.

Comment: Do you need winscp maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SCP client like WinSCP to copy files from remote ( Linux ) machine since Windows doesn't have a SSH / SCP client preinstalled.